# convert sql bit into checkbox into desktop application using c#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a table like city and its have cityID primary int, cityName varchar(50), cityActive bit. I have directly bound into data grid using linq.

DGCustomers.DataSource = db.city.ToList();

But cityActive display into data grid as string always, so there is any direct method exists which convert its into checkbox. I know that we can do this using loop, and we can add column using form design or run time. but i want to confirm that if available any direct method. Please confirm us any one.

Comment: Are you using any ORM framework for your database? Like EntityFramework or Linq2SQL? Also what DataGridColumn are you using in the GridView?

Comment: yes, i am using .edmx.

Comment: So have you added a Checkbox column to your GridView?

Comment: yes and cityActive column wants display as checkbox, i.e its active or not. so don't want to add one more column

Comment: Consider using a System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView instead of System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid. The DataGridView class allows you to define the type of columns it displays. You can say that the column that shows property cityActive is a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn, and thus this column shows a CheckBox

Comment: @Ajai Harald is right, use DataGridView

Comment: DataGridView: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAsRV.png

Comment: Thanks for reply us, Now, I have found a solution, I have created a column with cActive and set the DatapropertyName = "cityActive" and set displayIndex accordilngly,

Answer (score 0):

I have created a column with cActive and set the DatapropertyName = "cityActive" and set displayIndex accordilngly. In this case its directly bind the column from datasource. So no need to create extra columns, just need to map with DatapropertyName.